# Enable remote connection for SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

On my server I have two SQL Servers, a production server and a testing server. I have gone through the process of making sure that the *Allow remote connection* is tick for both servers. I also I configure the port number in Sql Server Configuration Manager.

I first configured the 1 server for port 1433 which is the default port and the other one to port 1434. After some research I found that port 1434 is for named instances and 1433 is for IP instances. Both my servers is named instances. So for testing purposes I configured the one for port 1434 and the other one 1435. But the connection fail for named instance on 1434.

According to an article I've red was that for configuring named instances the *dynamic port* should be blank. I did that as well but it keeps on failing.

I also configured the firewall to allow port 1434.

The tricky part is I want to access both of the servers.

This is the error I get
[image]

Any assistance would be appreciated

Comment: Can you paste error as text,images are blocked in some domains

Comment: The Port 1434 is used for DAC connection with SQL Server. Assign port other then 1433 and 1434 and try to connect using  `SERVER_NAME\INSTASENAME,PORT`

Comment: @RajeshRanjan now I get "no such host is known" error when I add the port number

Comment: did you put "," after instance name?

Comment: @RajeshRanjan yes I did

Comment: Verify SQL Server Browser service is running??